# calling a variable from another class JAVA

Tags: java, variables, private, getter, accessor

Ok so I made three classes. One is a tester and the other two are blueprint classes.I cannot seem call the  private double cart variable  from the blueprint class ScanShop to ShoppingCart. I thought of using accessors and getters but I am now confusing myself and don't know where I am going wrong. Here is my code:

```
package exercise3;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ScanShop 
{
private double cart =0;

public double getcart()
{
    return cart;
}
public void setcart(double cart)
{
    this.cart =cart;
}
public void scan()
{

    //the prices of items
    double p1;
    double p2;
    double p3;
    double total;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("what price is item one?");
    p1 = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("What is price of item two?");
    p2= in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("And what is the price of the third item?");
    p3= in.nextDouble();

      total = p1 + p2 + p3;


    System.out.printf("The total bill is %.2f\n\n", total);


    setcart(total);

    System.out.println("the cart is: " + getcart());

    in.close();




}
}
```

Here is the ShoppingCart blueprint class:

```
package exercise3;

import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class ShoppingCart 
{
ScanShop amount = new ScanShop();





public void getbill()
{

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"your total is: " +  amount.getcart());
}

public void billCal()
{
    String answer;
    int number;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    /*System.out.println("please enter how much your bill is:...");
    //how much bill is:
    cart = in.nextDouble();
    in.nextLine();
    System.out.printf("you have entered: %.2f", cart);*/

    System.out.println("Do you have a loyalty card? y or n");
    // asking do you have loyalty card
    answer= input.next();

    if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
    {

        amount.setcart(amount.getcart()*0.9);

        //other vouchers to discount
        System.out.println("thats great! do you have a voucher: "
                + "\n(1) £5  "
                + "\n(2) £10 "
                + "\n (3) no vouchers");
        number= input.nextInt();
        switch(number)
        {
        case 1 :
            amount.setcart(amount.getcart()-5);
            getbill(); 
            break;

        case 2 : 
            amount.setcart(amount.getcart()-10);
            getbill();
            break;

        default : 
            getbill();
            break;
        }
    }

    else
    {
        getbill();
    }

    input.close();
}//closing billCal

}
```

And finally here is my tester class:

```
package exercise3;

public class ShoppingCart_Test {
public static void main (String [] arg){
    ShoppingCart customerOne = new ShoppingCart();
    //c1 is customer one
    ScanShop  c1 = new ScanShop();


    c1.scan();
    customerOne.billCal();


}
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it requires an introduction to OO programming. Stack Overflow is not a substitute for a good book, tutorial or teacher.

Comment: `in.close();` Did you know that your program crashes due to a `NoSuchElementException` being thrown?

Answer (score 2):

You can't reach a `private` variable of a class from another class. `private` fields are only accessible from the owner class of the field.

If you want to get the value of a private field you should create public getter method for that field.

Comment: So i changed in ScanShop class: the private double cart to public double cart and i still get the same error. Are public getters and setters the same as private?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use *ScanShop*'s *cart* variable in the *ShoppingCart*'s *billCal* method you should change it to take a number (double) and work on it. Don't create instance of *ScanShop* inside of the *ShoppingCart* if you're creating both of them in the tester. Like change your code to this:

```
public void getbill(double total)
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"your total is: " + total);
}
```

and do your billCal like this:

```
public void billCal(Double totalAmount)
{
    (...)
switch(number)
    {
    case 1 :
        getbill(totalAmount-5); 
        break;
    (...)
}
```

And finally your main method to this:

```
public static void main (String [] arg){
ShoppingCart customerOne = new ShoppingCart();
ScanShop  c1 = new ScanShop();


c1.scan();
customerOne.billCal(c1.getCart());
```

}

Comment: Thank you that was the way I was going to do it but i wanted to know if you could use two classes on the same tester.